# socks5 protocol question

Tags: network-protocols, socks

When a client sends the packet with the version number the number of methods and the methods, based an what does the server repply with a method ? How is the server choosing from the methods list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the [SOCKS v5 specification](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1928.txt).